# assigning a label to a variable

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7

I am getting a traceback error at the for loop (line 9).

> TypeError: #'NoneType' object is not iterable

I was wondering if fcList is empty. I also thought leaving arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() parameters empty provided all the available feature classes in the environment. If that's the case then I was wondering if I should define fc before I use the list.

here's my code:

```
import arcpy
#set geoprocessing environments
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Student/PythonGP100/Data/SanJuan.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True #Can also enter 1 for true and 0 for false
#Create list of feature classes in SanJuan.gdb
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
#Create a loop to buffer lakes & Streams
bufferList = []
for fc in fcList:  #this line gives the error traceback <module> TypeError: #'NoneType' object is not iterable
    if fc == "Lakes" or fc == "Streams":
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(fc, fc + "Buffer", "1000 meters")
        bufferList.append(fc + "Buffer")

#adding union to bufferlist
arcpy.Union_analysis(bufferList, "WaterBuffers")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I get rid of the error? is fcList empty? I thought leaving arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() parameters empty provided all the available feature classes in the environment? If that's the case then do i need to define fc before I use the list or if functions?

Comment: @StargazingFish, What error? You haven't shared it with us.

Comment: is SanJuan.gdb the file you want to create or read from?

Comment: Please copy and paste the full error message into your post.

Comment: I did. Traceback <module> TypeError: #'NoneType' object is not iterable on line 9

Comment: @kttii read from

Comment: Please keep editing your question to improve it with this requested information.

Comment: try this link which gets the featureclasses from the datasets : https://geonet.esri.com/thread/29036

Comment: @PolyGeo Ive asked multiple questions. Why am I getting the Traceback TypeError 'Nonetype' object is not iterable on line 9? Is the empty value fc or fcList? If it's fcList why is fcList empty if I defined it as arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() ? If fc is empty or undefined how do I define it and where specifically?

Comment: @StargazingFish PolyGeo is trying to help you form your question correctly because as it currently stands, it does not meet the rules of this site because doesn't provide enough information.  Our comments are to help prompt you to reedit your question to make it better to understand and answer.

Comment: If you have not yet done so, please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols. Many potential answerers only read the question body because they do not have enough time (which they volunteer) to read a comment trail to try and synthesize a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that you'll get the error that you're seeing and not get an error earlier in your script is if there is no geodatabase at `C:/Student/PythonGP100/Data/SanJuan.gdb`.

If you had feature classes within feature datasets or if you had no feature classes at all, `fcList` would just be an empty list. It's not an empty list, but an instance of None--according to the error message. An instance of `None` is exactly what you get when you `ListFeatureClasses` in a non-existent workspace.

Make sure that the path is correct.